# Deriving velocity and why is it the integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, physics, proof-explanation

If I have initial velocity $V_0$ and I want to know how much distance is covered after $t$ seconds with acceleration $a$ meters per second, I tried this (where $V_t = V_0 + at$):

$$d = \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{t}{k} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(V_0 + \frac{i \cdot (V_t-V_0)}{k-1}\right)$$

For example if $V_0 = 20$ and $t=3$ and $a=10$ then we could keep approximating:

$V_3 = \frac{3}{2}(20) + \frac{3}{2}(50)$

$V_3 = \frac{3}{3}(20) + \frac{3}{3}(35) + \frac{3}{3}(50)$

$V_3 = \frac{3}{4}(20) + \frac{3}{4}(30) +  \frac{3}{4}(40) +\frac{3}{4}(50)$

And so on. I generalized it to $k$ terms and went to infinity and simplified the algebra. If you do the math the $k$ terms cancel out and you get this:

$V_t = V_0t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$

Which seems to be correct from what I am see on Google.

But how do I make the connection to calculus where people start talking about derivatives and integrals regarding distance, velocity, and acceleration? I don't understand how we "know" to use those things there and why they match the result I just got.

Comment: You could watch [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr). It explains the connections quite well, I think.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. I'm near the end of the first video and it looks like the answer is "Any time we're adding up a bunch of little things (like I did in my post), we can use an integral"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d(t) = \int_0^t v(\tau) d \tau = \int_0^t (v_0+ a\tau) d \tau$.

Evaluating the Riemann integral using a uniform grid gives
$d(t) = \lim_k {t \over k} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} V_{{i t \over k}}  = \lim_k {t \over k} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (V_0 + a{i t \over k}) = V_0 t + {1 \over 2} a t^2$.

Comment: I believe the denominator of the $it$ part should be $k-1$ (or the bounds need to adjust to compensate) edit: I guess the evaluation ends up being the same since $k$ goes to infinity anyway; I had $k-1$ there because of the $k$-term logic I was using in my post

Comment: Why? This is a standard Riemann sum, I am just evaluating $V_t$ at the left side of each interval.

Comment: Because in using $k$ terms in my sum, there were $k-1$ "separation" points where velocity was added to the previous term

Comment: Well, since ${k-1 \over k} \to 1$ the answer will end up the same, but a standard Riemann approximation would be ${t \over k} (V_0+ \cdots + V_{{k-1 \over k}t})$, or you could take the right hand sides of the intervals to get ${t \over k} (V_{{1 \over k}t}+ \cdots + V_{t})$.